# scala regex filter wrapped elements

Tags: regex, scala

I have input in form of Strings like the following

```
ellipse {
    attribute = foo

    ellipse {
        attribute = foo
        line {
            attribute = foo
            attribute = foo
            attribute = foo
        }
        line {
            attribute = foo
            attribute = foo
        }
    }
}
```

Basically it is about 2d-elements, that are able to hold other 2d-elements  inside them. My task is to write a regex, that can seperate parent-elements from their children, so they can be parsed seperately.
In the case of:

```
rectangle1{
    attribute = foo
}
ellipse1{
    attribute = foo
    ellipse{
        rectangle{
            attribute = foo
        }
    }
}
```

I want to be able to `regex.findAllIn(string)` and then have only the rectangle1 and the ellipse1 strings, so I can parse them.
Im no expert with regexes but I made an attempt, which fails of course:

I tried to:

> (?s)(?!((ellipse|point|line) \\{)).+**(ellipse|point|line)** \\{.*\\}

get all the ellipses or points or lines, which

> (?s)(?!((ellipse|point|line) \\{)).+(ellipse|point|line) **\\{.*\\}**

include something, but

> (?s)**(?!(**(ellipse|point|line) \\{)).+(ellipse|point|line) \\{.*\\}

**don't**

> (?s)**(?!((ellipse|point|line) \\{))**.+(ellipse|point|line) \\{.*\\}

have something like **'ellipse {'** or **'point {'** above them,

but this doesnt work...

There most likely is a way to do what I want, but as I said I'm not an expert with regexes. If you have an answer for me, I would be very grateful for an explanation, since I would like to understand the solution.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: If I understand your task correctly then I don't think regular expression are the right tool here.

Comment: sooo.. what would you do instead? For string-split operations i will need regexes anyway, right?

Comment: If you are using scala, I'd suggest to use [Scala Parser Combinators](https://github.com/scala/scala-parser-combinators) for this task. ([Some tutorial](http://bitwalker.org/scala/programming/tutorial/2013/08/10/learn-by-example-scala-parser-combinators/)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pure regex are not very good fit for this task. You have to use recursive regex, and Java (and hence Scala) currently don't support them.

However, as you are using Scala, you can take advantage of powerful [Parser Combinator](https://github.com/scala/scala-parser-combinators) library:

```
object ParserCombinator extends App with JavaTokenParsers with PackratParsers {

  case class Attr(value:String)
  case class Fig2d(name:String, attrs:List[Attr], children:List[Fig2d])

  def fig2d:Parser[Fig2d] = (ident <~ "{") ~ rep(attr) ~ (rep(fig2d) <~ "}") ^^ {
    case name ~ attrs ~ children => Fig2d(name, attrs, children)
  }

  def attr:Parser[Attr] = "attribute" ~> "=" ~> "\\S+".r ^^ Attr.apply

  def fig2dList = rep(fig2d)

  val input =
    """
      |rectangle1{
      |    attribute = foo
      |}
      |ellipse1{
      |    attribute = foo
      |    ellipse{
      |        rectangle{
      |            attribute = foo
      |        }
      |    }
      |}
    """.stripMargin


  println(parseAll(fig2dList, input))
}
```

Prints:

```
 [13.5] parsed: List(Fig2d(rectangle1,List(Attr(foo)),List()), Fig2d(ellipse1,List(Attr(foo)),List(Fig2d(ellipse,List(),List(Fig2d(rectangle,List(Attr(foo)),List()))))))
```

Comment: thanks, could you explain what the (ident[...]) in line 6 of your program does? I have an idea, but i found no use like this in the tutorial you mentioned.

Comment: @Julian, it is defined in `JavaTokenParsers`: "Anything that is a valid Java identifier, according to
[The Java Language Spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8)". I used it to match 2d element's name. Obviously you can replace it with regex parser or anything you like.  Or you mean the whole line?